# Defining read-only properties within a factory-function, using getters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

So, it appears, there are two working approaches to defining read-only properties in JS - with **Object.defineProperty** or a **getter**.

In my case, I have to stick to the getter appoach, but considering the context, it does not seem to fit in just right, as I am implementing the getter within the **LoyaltyCard** factory-function.

Properties 'id', 'balance' and 'discount' have to be difined to read-only. Starting from 'id', there is a syntax error, returning: "**Unexpected token, expected ;**".

Is there a way to implement the getter neatly, as it is suggested in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get or maybe I'm missing something?

```
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.ceil((max - min + 1) * Math.random()) + min - 1;
}

function generateId() {
  return Array(4).fill(1).map(value => rand(1000, 9999)).join('-');
}  


let LoyaltyCard = function(name, sum) {
  this.owner = name;
  this.id; //unfinished
  this.balance = sum; 
  this.discount = 0; 
  this.orders = Array.of(sum);
}

LoyaltyCard.prototype.getFinalSum = function(sum) {
  let calculatedDiscount;

  if (this.balance >= 3000 && this.balance < 5000) {
    calculatedDiscount = 3;
  } else if (this.balance >= 5000 && this.balance < 10000){
    calculatedDiscount = 5;
  } else if (this.balance >= 10000) {
    calculatedDiscount = 7; 
  }

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'discount', {
    value: calculatedDiscount
  });

  finalSum = sum * (1 - this.discount / 100);
  this.orders.push(sum);
  return finalSum;
}

LoyaltyCard.prototype.append = function(sum) {
  this.orders.push(sum);
  return Object.defineProperty(this, 'balance', {
    value: this.balance += sum
  });
}

LoyaltyCard.prototype.show = function() {
  console.log(`Card ${this.id}:\nOwner: ${this.owner}\nBalance: ${this.balance} Q\nCurrent discount: ${this.discount} %\nOrders:\n  #1 on ${this.orders[0]} Q\n  #2 on ${this.orders[1]} Q`);
}

//Call sample:

const card = new LoyaltyCard('John Doe', 6300);

let newOrderSum = 7000;
let finalSum = card.getFinalSum(newOrderSum);
console.log(`The final order amount for the order on ${newOrderSum} Q using the loyalty card will be 
${finalSum} Q. ${card.discount} %. discount applied`);

card.append(newOrderSum);
console.log(`Loyalty card balance after the purchase ${card.balance} Q.`);
card.show();
```

Comment: You wouldn't want the getter to be defined like that anyway, as you'd get a new random id each time the property was accessed.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use `defineProperty`?

Comment: It is not me having something against difineProperty, but a given task to define certain properties as read-only, using getters (presumably, as it is a more modern approach)

Comment: Only using getter will not make the property read only. If you directly assign that property it will take precedent over the getter

Comment: And what if it is exactly what I need, but only at a certain point of execution? Setters enter the game?

Comment: Added current implementation with defineProperty used. Have not yet figured it out for the 'id' property, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider "module pattern" to encapsulate the data your want to store as "private". Here the demo

```
function LoyaltyCard(name, sum) {
  let owner = name;
  let id; // get id from your generateId()
  let balance = sum;
  let discount = 0;
  let orders = Array.of(sum);

  function getFinalSum(sum) {
    /* implementation */
    balance += sum; // DEMO ONLY
    return sum; //  DEMO ONLY
  }

  function append(sum) { /* implementation */ }

  function show() { /* implementation */ }

  return {
    get name() {
      return owner;
    },
    set name(name) {
      owner = name;
    },
    get balance() {
      return balance;
    },
    getFinalSum,
    append,
  };
}

const card = LoyaltyCard('peter', 100);
console.log(card.balance); // 100
console.log(card.getFinalSum(200)); // 200
console.log(card.balance); // 300
card.balance = 50; // silently fail
console.log(card.balance); // 300
```

For more information about "module pattern" please read YDKJS
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md